# ACLs on NFS mounted directory

Tags: linux, nfs, acl

I'm trying to set an acl on the contents of a directory so all members of a group called prod_grp can write to a directory that is NFS mounted from another server. The acl is below:

```
# file: prod-sites
# owner: root
# group: prod_grp
user::rwx
user:apache:r-x
group::rwx
group:prod_grp:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:apache:r-x
default:group::rwx
default:group:prod_grp:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

The problem I'm running into is that members of prod_grp are not getting write permissions and I don't understand why. Root can write to the directory fine. This is NFSv3 so v4 ACLs can't be involved and the folder is mounted rw.

I've done this several times in the past and never had a problem until this time.

Comment: Since this is v3, are the UIDs/GIDs consistent between the client and server?

Comment: Yes, the UIDs and GIDs are the same.

Comment: The ACL support for the in 1997 withdrawn POSIX draft ACLs was not part of the NFSv3 standard and not implemented by Linux. Are you shure that Linux meanwhile includes ACL support for NFSv3?